# The restrictions imposed by the Constrained flag in the strtoset function were violated - inserting sql string in mdx

Tags: sql, date, parameters, ssas, mdx

I for the life of me can't figure out why the MDX in SSAS won't accept my date parameter. I have a data-set which runs off MDX which has a month parameter that takes in a month and year (see the screenshot included). I have a sql statement that outputs multiple months/years so the user can choose a month/year however when you go to run the report and select the month it gives the strtoset function violated error. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. 
[MDX statement taking in the sql supplied variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxXea.png)

The sql output (which is going to into the parameter looks like this (below)...

April 2017
May 2017
June 2017
July 2017
....
It perfectly matches the way the values of the mdx dates are formatted

Answer (score 0):

Is the parameter a multi select? It looks like you have multiple months that you are appending into the one date member.

I would guess that Time.calendar months.April 2017 would work by itself? Not sure how good your MDX is but the constrained error is saying your dimension members are not valid.

If it's multi select you'd need something like

StrToSet
(
Time.calendar months.april 2017,
Time.calendar months.may 2017,
.....
)

Comment: It is multi select which appears to be the issue. thanks. I switched it so you can only pick one value. Would I just encase the entire parameter code with teh strtoset() function if I wanted it to be multiselect again? I'm unsure of how to use that funciton correctly in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try looking at the SSRs JOIN function. This combines multi valued Param values with a separator.

assuming your Param values are like Time.calendar months.blah then you can have something like

StrToSet ( join(param.value,","))

Might not be exact syntax but worth a play.